# Use different CarrierWave uploaders for one Model based on attributes of another Model - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, model, carrierwave

I am working on a Rails project where a user (model "User") can upload a document (model "Document"). I am using CarrierWave to upload the documents. The user can have different types of accounts (free or premium). If the user has a free account, I only want to allow them to upload certain types of files.

The CarrierWave Uploader file does not know what current_user is, so I can't check it that way. And I am at an understanding that using current_user in the Document model is bad practice.

What is the best way for me to handle this?

Comment: just use for that controllers.

Comment: Does the document model have any relationship with User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def extension_white_list
  return %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf docx) if model.user.account_type?(:free)
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png pdf docx doc xlsx xls odt ods csv txt)
end
```

You can access the `Document` model inside uploader by the variable `model`. If `Document` model is connected with `User` model via relationship, you can do something like given above. Please note that you have to define `account_type` method in `User` model.